# C++ Convert from defined superclass to subclass using =

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to make something to define a storage container for any subclass of `Tag`; i.e. `TAG_String`, in the code in the following files:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Tag.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    nbt::TAG_Compound d("Data");
    d["str"] = new nbt::TAG_String("str");
    d["str"].value("hi");
    cout << d["str"].value() << endl;
    //cout << val() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Tag.cpp

```
#include "Tag.h"

using namespace std;

nbt::Tag::Tag(string nam){
    name = nam;
}

/*nbt::Tag& nbt::Tag::operator=(nbt::Tag& nw){
    nbt::Tag *tis = this;
    tis = nw;
    return tis&;
}*/

string nbt::Tag::Name(){
    return name;
}

void nbt::Tag::Name(string nam){
    name = nam;
}

void nbt::TAG_Compound::load(string file){

}

void nbt::TAG_Compound::save(string file){

}

nbt::Tag& nbt::TAG_Compound::operator[](string lookup){
    for(int i=0;i<val.size();i++){
        if(val[i].Name() == lookup){
            return val[i];
        }
    }
    nbt::Tag tag("");
    val.push_back(tag);
    return val[val.size()-1];
}

void nbt::TAG_String::load(string file){

}

void nbt::TAG_String::save(string file){

}

string nbt::TAG_String::value(){
    return val;
}

void nbt::TAG_String::value(string v){
    val = v;
}
```

(In that i know there are empty functions; they will be used later)

Tag.h

```
#ifndef NBTTAG_H_INCLUDED
#define NBTTAG_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace nbt{

    class Tag {

        std::string name;

    public:

        //void save(std::string);
        //void load(std::string);
        std::string Name();
        void Name(std::string);
        Tag(std::string);
        //Tag& operator=(Tag&);

    };

    class TAG_Compound : public Tag {

        std::vector<Tag> val;

    public:

        void save(std::string);
        void load(std::string);
        Tag& operator[](std::string);
        using Tag::Tag;

    };
    class TAG_String : public Tag {

        std::string val;

    public:

        void save(std::string);
        void load(std::string);
        std::string value();
        void value(std::string);
        using Tag::Tag;

    };
}
#endif // NBTTAG_H_INCLUDED
```

Is there even a way? (I am conviced there is, so if anyone can prove me wrog, that would be a good thing.)

Comment: What's your problem? At the moment, I can't tell at all.

Comment: You should use `const std::string&` instead of just `std::string` as parameters to your functions, it would avoid unnecessary copying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a class which contains a reference to the Tag class, e.g. as follows:

```
class Container {
public:
    Container( Tag *tag ) {
        containedTag = tag;
    }

    Tag *containedTag;
};
```

Then instantiate it as follows:

```
TAG_String tag = TAG_String( "String!" );
Container container = Container( &tag );
```

I've noticed you have attempted to do something similar with the TAG_Compound class, however the vector is only accepting Tag values, and would need to accept a pointer or a reference instead.  Remember, in C++, you can only pass a child class instance off as an instance of its parent class if you're passing a reference or pointer to it, you cannot actually **make it** an instance of the parent class.

Comment: I tried to make it use `Tag*`, but that crashed. I didnt try to `Tag&` though. I'll try that.

Comment: didn't work. Got 31 errors. I suppose I should have mentioned that I am using C++11. Trying to define a function similarly.

Comment: whelp. that sortof worked. Now I just need to use specific functions for `TAG_String` which of course doesnt work.

Comment: Normally within an object oriented setup you use base-methods of the base-object in order to return or operate on anything needed.  This is all about interface design and therefore you may want to look up some tutorials on object oriented design, e.g. http://www.oodesign.com/

Comment: I worked out a way to do it using `virtual` functions.